# How to ensure that MySQL column only accepts X number of characters?

Tags: mysql, types

I've been doing some searching on the Internet, but I can't for the life figure this out:

Can I force a MySQL table column to ONLY accept a set number of characters (e.g. 5 numbers ONLY, not 4 numbers nor 6 numbers)? I've read the MySQL documentation for some various data types but haven't really discovered anything yet.

In a rather unfortunate move, I can't perform reg-ex checking in PHP that easily right now, and would like to take the easy way out by forcing this check in the database itself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write a layer of code to do things like  `trigger BEFORE INSERT`

Answer (score 1):

you can probably do this with a check constraint on the table

Comment: "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: that makes it completely useless

Answer (score 1):

Is it not possible for you to check the length of string for that column in php before sending it to database?

If you still need it in database level then, there is function **[Length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)** in mysql. you might want to check it out.